# Page Argument In Drupal

Tags: drupal, menu

I have a block in that I have a search button, when clicks that button I pass this url (www.jksb.com/saleorderlist?field_month=4) to drupal menu. In page argument of menu I need to provide parameter (field_month).My page argument is like this: 'page argument' => array(1), but it doesn't work for me. I need somebody to help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I solve to this problem.

saleordermonthly.module

function sale_order_monthly_menu() {
    $items = array();

```
$items["saleOrderMonthlyList"] = array(
'title' => 'Sale Order Monthly Report',
'description'=>'Sale Order Monthly',
'page callback' => 'sale_order_monthly_loadAllrecord',
//'page arguments' => array($para),
'access arguments' => array('access saleOrderMonthlyList'),
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
'file' => 'sale_order_monthly.admin.inc',
'access callback' => TRUE
);
```

return $items;
}

saleordermonthly.inc

```
enter code here
<?php 
function sale_order_monthly_loadAllrecord()
{   
$para='';
$query = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if(count($query) > 0){
    $para= $query['field_month'];
};
```

}
?>

Comment: Thanks for drupal_get_query_parameters()!  I looked for that for way too long!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your argument in query string but if you use "page argument' => array(1)", it means you want the second segment/component of the path to be passed as the first parameter of your callback function. (you can still get the parameter inside your callback but you must use the "$_GET" variable in that case).

For instance :

```
$items['my-module/%/edit'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
```

Here, "%" is a wildcard at position "1" ("my-module" is at position 0 and "edit" at position 2). This is the value that will be passed as the first parameter in the callback function ("mymodule_abc_edit")

In your case your path in "hook_menu" should look as follow:

```
'saleorderlist/%'
```

then if you call the path "saleorderlist/4", "4" will be passed as the first parameter of your callback function:

function my_callback($field_month) {
  echo $field_month;//Will echo "4"
}

More info about hook_menu here ("Wildcards in Paths" section for your current question) : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried as u said in above. But when 'saleorderlist?field_month=0' is called I got "page not found" message in my saleorderlist page.

Comment: Yes that's because you must register another item with the path "saleorderlist" (which is different from the path "saleorderlist/%"